# Use [apply(lambda x: x.hour)] to add Time Column to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have read a csv file and stored it in a dataframe. I want to then create a view of the dataframe containing the columns: 'x','y','z','q' and then add the column 'ptime' to this dataframe, then add a new column - 'time_window' - that contains the hour of the day.

I don't think I created or added the columns correctly and I definitely did not do the apply() correctly

```
def transform():
   data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
   df = pd.data(columns=['x','y','z','q'])
   df = df1['ptime'] = Series(np.random.randn(sLength), index=df1.index)
   df = df2.insert(5, 'time_window', [apply(lambda x: x.hour)], True) 
   return df.to_csv('output1.csv')
```